# How to reliably determine write access of a file

Tags: .net, file-permissions, uac, file-access

Searching the internet, I found two ways to determine whether a process can write to a file; checking the permissions and attempting a write. I decided to try the two out and came up with a surprising result.

It appears that checking the security permissions on the file reports the process has write access to files in UAC-protected directories whether or not the process is running in elevated mode. Using an attempted write (System.IO), on the other hand, reports that the process has write access to files in UAC-protected directories only if the process is running in elevated mode.

**My questions are as follows:**

1. Why does using the security permissions approach give wrong results?
2. In which cases would one want to use use security permissions instead of a real write attempt?

Here is the code I used for the test.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var filename in new[]{@"C:\Windows\win.ini",
                                          Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%tmp%\temp.txt")})
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}", filename);
                Console.WriteLine("Write Permission : {0}", WriteAccess(filename));
                Console.WriteLine("IO Write Attempt : {0}", WriteAccess2(filename));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            var principal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static bool WriteAccess(string filename)
        {
            var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
            permissionSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, filename));
            return permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet);
        }

        static bool WriteAccess2(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                // assumes the file exists
                using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    return true;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output (non-elevated process)

```
File Name: C:\Windows\win.ini
Write Permission : True
IO Write Attempt : False

File Name: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.txt
Write Permission : True
IO Write Attempt : True
```

Output (elevated process)

```
File Name: C:\Windows\win.ini
Write Permission : True
IO Write Attempt : True

File Name: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.txt
Write Permission : True
IO Write Attempt : True
```